# Batting Average after replay?

Tags: baseball, mlb, trivia

Since Major League Baseball has implemented replay on home runs, has the batter's batting average increased due to the wait the pitcher has between pitches?

Comment: It's far to soon to even begin to think about being able to control for the presence of replay in baseball. It's only the third or fourth season and it only gets used a handful of times each year.

Comment: @waxeagle According to MLB.com instant replay was used 58 times in 2010 alone. That is far more than a hand full of times. The following link shows each occurrence back to 2008 which would suggest that the pithing stats I am looking for are likely available somewhere. I simply can't find them yet. ( http://mlb.mlb.com/news/article.jsp?ymd=20090527&content_id=4989756&vkey=news_mlb&c_id=mlb)

Comment: Are you specifically looking for isolated stats in these games vs the league average? Also when we're talking about 2430 games, 58 instances is not a substantial sample.

Comment: @waxeagle Between 2008 - 2010 "Altogether, instant replay has been used 123 times since its introduction, with 48 of those instances resulting in overturned calls..." Averaging 41 times replay was used per season with the number growing each year. Again, these stats are from MLB.com and only reference the 2008, 2009 and 2010 seasons.

Comment: @waxeagle Yes, I would like to see if the batter is gaining an advantage because of the wait in between pitches while instant replay is being reviewed. So, comparing the league avg to these isolated stats would be appropriate.

Comment: Also are you looking for the single at-bat or for the rest of the game? inning? what stats are you actually looking for? this is going to be quite hard because 1. this information is not in a box score and as such is not easily queryable. 2. No one seems to have a complete record of games where it's been used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8675/discussion-between-wax-eagle-and-e1suave)

Comment: I tend to agree with wax eagle.  While the impact of replay is something that will be debated for years I'm sure, the number of variables that are affecting BA and ERA are so great that to definitively assert that replay is the primary factor in the change would be misleading.  

As a side note, it has been said that the game has changed in the last few years to benefit the pitchers (more perfect games, no-hitters, etc. than ever before).

Answer (score 1):

Probably no impact- The average wait time is probably around 2-3 minutes after replay. Pitchers wait a lot during baseball, and something as minor as 3 minutes probably has no effect- meetings on the mound, Manny Ramirez homeruns, and other minor events all make pitchers wait longer between pitches.

The only thing I could think of would be if ruling a HR a double and vice versa had an impact because of whether it made the pitcher pitch from the windup vs. the stretch. I always assumed that the windup was what most pitchers preferred (after all, they only do the stretch when necessary), [but according to this article](http://www.hardballtimes.com/main/blog_article/does-the-stretch-cost-a-pitcher-fastball-speed/), there is no effect.